# Fedora PHP "failed to open stream: Permission denied"

Tags: php, linux, error-handling, fedora

So I've got Apache on web server running Fedora. I'm trying to write into the text file.

```
if(!empty($_POST['versionWrite'])){
$file = fopen(APP_DIR."/resources/version.txt", "w");
fwrite($file, $_POST['versionWrite'].PHP_EOL);
fclose($file);
}
```

And when I execute the code, I get this:

```
Warning: fopen(/var/www/spumprnagle/resources/version.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/spumprnagle/head.php on line 28

Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/spumprnagle/head.php on line 29

Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/spumprnagle/head.php on line 30
```

This happens in every script working with files. And I have no idea what shall I do to grant Apache permissions to edit files.

Thanks for your time :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem**: The apache user doesn't have the permission to write file.

**Solution**:

```
chown -R apache:apache path/to/directory
```

where **apache** is the default user for fedora and path/to/directory is the path of the directory containing the files with you want to write.

If you want to give the permission to a single file then omit **-R**

Comment: OK, so this... was working... but probably by trnsfering file ownership to Apache I removed permissions from FTP server... any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

OK, I add this answer for who are searching for answer on **Fedora**. I changed file permissions to 777 and file ownership to apache:apache but it keeps throwing the same error. finally I found that in some versions of Fedora **SElinux** prevents **Httpd** from writing files. The solution is to disable SElinux as follow:

```
 vim /etc/selinux/config
```

then edit the file as follow:

```
 SELINUX=disabled
```

Then Restart.
It worked for me. 
Happy coding.

Comment: Thank you.  It's not something I would generally think would be the case - but it is!

Answer (score 0):

I would start by checking permissions on the file `/var/www/spumprnagle/resources/version.txt` to ensure that it's writeable by the web user. Since you tagged `fedora` here, I believe that's usually the `apache` user, so try `chown apache:apache /var/www/spumprnagle/resources/version.txt`.

If you're unsure of permission setting you can always temporarily set 777, e.g. `chmod 777 /var/www/spumprnagle/resources/version.txt`. If that resolves the issue, you can adjust the permissions down to something more reasonable (644).

Comment: So, I tired that and it works with 777 but not with 644. What does the level (if it is any level) mean? I get that I'm somehow adjusting the level of permissions needed to access the file, but I don't really understand this. Is there any problem in letting at 777? I don't work with Linux, so I'm sorry if these questions are somehow dumb and answers for them obvious... Also can I set this for whole project folder, or have I to set it for each file manually?

Thanks.